# Maven - ojdbc14.jar dependency issue

Tags: maven-dependency

Facing the following error for Maven Spring Jdbc Project:

```
Missing artifact for ojdbc14.jar
```

I am using Eclipse Photon , Maven 3.0

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLHp6.png)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ojdbc14/ojdbc14 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>ojdbc14</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How do you find the group id? Did you try the configuration in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.jdbc/ojdbc14/12.2.0.1?

Comment: Hi sam..thanks..got it from maven repository. Link which you shared refers to Oracle 12 version , but i need for Oracle 10g

Comment: Please add the minimum pom.xml reproducing the error.